# How to change the source code in an installed python package?

Tags: python, github, package, edit, tensorflow-probability

I want to change the source code in a python package. Specifically, I would like to change the following line from the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/9e50fa39f37216dd084c24aa3dd14ab0d4dee926/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/conv_variational.py#L384:)

I want to edit:

```
outputs_shape = outputs.shape.as_list()
```

To:

```
outputs_shape = tf.shape(outputs)
```

I know how to do this in google Colab, but I am running my code on a remote server.

If I don't want to create a virtual environment and don't have access to the files from where it is downloaded, is there a way (**python code**) to modify an imported package if it is originally installed as `pip install tensorflow_probability`?

Comment: You can fork it on GitHub, change the line and then `pip install` your fork.

Comment: That's assuming you (somehow) don't have write access to the local folder where `pip` downloaded the packages to, which would be easier to edit.

Comment: I am running my code on a remote server. I cannot `pip install` myself (an admin installs the missing packages) unless I create a virtual environment. My question is if I don't want to run in a virtual environment, is there a code I can use to modify the imported package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, you can get the path of module by just doing this:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> print mymodule.__file__
'/path/to/mymodule.py'
```

And now you got the file, you can open file and edit it accordingly!

I don't know if this a best idea or not or it may not work or harm other things also, but I have answered it because I had already done/tested  it. So.. I am suggesting you.

Comment: I cannot open that file (I don't have access, an admin installs the packages), because I am running on a remote server and then submit the job. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could send a PR if you think it's a generally beneficial change.

Comment: Hi Brian, late question here, so lets say the PR was done and accepted, how does one get the update locally? i added a PR to an open source project, and it was merged to main. however when i do a pip install --upgrade i did not get the change.

Answer (score 0):

To get path of a Python module from bash command line:

```
python3 -c 'import mymod; print(mymod.__file__);'
```